# Regression Analysis and Two-Sample t-Test Equivalence when Using a Binary Independent Variable

Tags: regression

"In regression analysis, when you use the first independent variable to indicate two groups (with values 0 and 1), the test statistic for the slope in regression is the same as the test statistic used in a two-sample t-test."

I intuitively understand what the concept is, but it is difficult to prove it mathematically, so please help.

Comment: I don't have a great mathematical proof but I can tell you that this is related to the fact that the t-test and linear regression both have the underlying [General Linear Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_linear_model). If you are looking for a stronger mathematical understanding of why these are the same, that is probably a good starting place.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/354803/fitted-values-of-a-simple-regression-with-intercept-and-dummy is closely related

Comment: Thank you for the comments. It has given me a rough idea of how to approach it.